# realtime object detection No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v1'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am following a Real time object detection on https://automaticaddison.com/real-time-object-recognition-using-a-webcam-and-deep-learning/#top and I have hit a road block I followed all the instructions and checked for any errors but still got this error
(I am using windows)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "object_detection_test.py",
 line 15, in <module>
     from utils import label_map_util   File "C:\Users\1rock\Documents\TensorFlow\models\research\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py",
 line 27, in <module>
     import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v1'
```

I used `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.9` just what the link above said and whilst running I got these packages and their versions and an error hope it would be relevant to the question

`ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.`

`ipywidgets 7.6.0 requires jupyterlab-widgets>=1.0.0, which is not installed.`

`Successfully installed absl-py-0.11.0 astor-0.8.1 gast-0.4.0 grpcio-1.34.0 importlib-metadata-3.3.0 markdown-3.3.3 numpy-1.19.4 protobuf-3.14.0 setuptools-51.0.0.post20201207 six-1.15.0 tensorboard-1.9.0 tensorflow-1.9.0 termcolor-1.1.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 werkzeug-1.0.1 wheel-0.36.2 zipp-3.4.0`

Comment: May you please share output of `print(tensorflow.__version__)`?

Comment: hiya I keep getting `Unable to initialize device PRN` whenever I input `print(tensorflow.__version__)` on the console

Comment: I looked at a possible fix activated the conda env then changed directory to the tensorflow folder but still keep getting the `Unable to initialize device PRN`

Comment: but according to the site that I followed it was tensorflow==1.9

Comment: Do it in python. Launch python and then execute `print(tensorflow.__version__)`

Comment: `(tensorflow_cpu) C:\Users\1rock>python
Python 3.6.12 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Sep  9 2020, 00:29:25) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(tensorflow.__version__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'tensorflow' is not defined`

Comment: is it this one or did i send something wrong?

Comment: you did nothing, I missed you need to import it firstly. Try `import tensorflow as tf` and `print(tf.__version__)`. We sill find if you have TF installed and its version

Comment: when I imported tensorflow i got a bunch of errors `import tensorflow as tf
C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py:32: UserWarning: loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:
C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.NOIJJG62EMASZI6NYURL6JBKM4EVBGM7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs\libopenblas.TXA6YQSD3GCQQC22GEQ54J2UDCXDXHWN.gfortran-win_amd64.dll
  stacklevel=1)`

Comment: `** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\1rock\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow_cpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226596/discussion-between-alex-k-and-iseths-gt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I used pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow==1.9

> line 27, in 
> import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat.v1'

TF 1.9 and earlier do not have `compat` module. To use it you need TF 1.10+. Its better to use conda install everywhere possible with conda virtual enviroment.

Also since you are using [tensorflow models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/r1.13.0) make sure you has corresponding version of repository, for example latest TF1.x version located [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/r1.13.0/research)